# Especificar servidor DNS ao resolver endereço

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns

Gostaria de realizar algo tipo um "nslookup" para resolver um endereço de um site através de meus servidores DNS, pois no exemplo abaixo, consigo somente através do DNS que tenho em minha maquina.

Como poderia informar o IP do meu servidor para resolver o endereço do Google por exemplo?

```
import socket

dns = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
print(dns)
```

Comment: Então, imagina que eu tenho servidores DNS meus e quero resolver endereços como google, facebook através dos meus DNS`s.

Comment: Isto, vamos supor que eu queira resolver o endereço www.terra.com através do DNS da google(8.8.8.8), como faria?

Comment: Se executar este comando no terminal, você vai entender "nslookup www.terra.com.br 8.8.8.8".
Com este comando resolve o endereço do terra através do DNS do google.

Comment: Talvez esta função ajude: `gethostbyname_ex('www.google.com')`, vê lá se isso ajuda

Comment: Não, eu preciso arrumar uma forma de passar o meu endereço de DNS para resolver o endereço "www.google.com:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nativamente parece não haver uma forma de fazer isto.

Como alternativa, você pode usar o módulo [`dns.resolver`](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/toc-dns.resolver-module.html) do conjunto de ferramentas [**dnspython**](http://www.dnspython.org/).

Para instalar no Ubuntu/Debian, via `apt-get`, faça:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dnspython
```

Se preferir instalar via `pip`:

```
sudo pip install dnspython
```

Para indicar o servidor, use o atributo [`nameservers`](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html#nameservers) do objeto `Resolver`.

```
import dns.resolver

resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)

# 8.8.8.8 é o DNS público do Google
resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']

answers = resolver.query('google.com')

for rdata in answers:
    print (rdata.address)
```

Mais informações:

- [Documentação](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/)
- [Exemplos](https://www.adampalmer.me/iodigitalsec/2014/11/21/performing-dns-queries-python/)

Comment: Excelente, foi só especificar meus DNS`s que consigo testar corretamente.
O "configure=False" serve para não utilizar o endereço DNS que esta na minha placa de rede, é isso?

Comment: Stderr's is back...

Comment: Não recoemnde "pip" com "sudo" como alternativa - principalmente num sistema em que o pacote existe - o pacote instalado pelo PIP vai conflitar com o pacote instalado pelo "apt"  e isso pode trazer problemas na configuração do sistema (por exemplo, um pacote apt que tenha o pacote instalado como PIP como pré-requisito não vai funcionar)

Comment: e em sistemas onde o pacote não existe (seja .deb, .rpm, ou no Windows como um todo) a melhor opção é criar um virtualenv: dessa forma a instalação com pip é local ao projeto  e não conflita com o Python do sistema.